Changing the contents of a variable passed to a function in Python. Syntactic sugar for creating a reference from a variable?
could I somehow reformat
def alterContents(dictionary,key):
    dictionary[key]="foobar"
myVar="hello"
alterContents(globals(),"myVar")
print(myVar)

to allow changing the contents of myVar by only passing a single argument to the function? Something like:
def alterContents(variable):
    variable="foobar" #psuedo code that would change the contents of the variable fed into it, in a similar manner to how you can set the data at memory address in most programming languages (for example, via "references" in C++).
myVar="hello"
alterContents(myVar)
print(myVar) # would print "foobar"

Or in other words: Im looking for a way of creating a pointer to any abstract variable (where I do not control how/where that variable is created & stored (although, since Python seems to store everything in dict()'s I suppose it could be somewhat safe to assume that to be the case)).
For my real world usecase, also simply returning the new value to let the caller of the function assign the variable afterwards would not work, as the my real world equivalent of alterContents does not actually alter the contents of the variable itself, but rather stores a "reference/pointer" for other machinery to make use of at a later time.
The obvious solution might be to do something like:
class Pointer:
    def __init__(self,dictionary,varName) -> None:
        self.dictionary=dictionary
        self.varName=varName
    @property
    def value(self):
        return self.dictionary[self.varName]
    @value.setter
    def value(self,val):
        self.dictionary[self.varName]=val

def alterContents(variable):
    variable.value="foobar" #psuedo code that would change the contents of the variable fed into it, in a similar manner to how you can set the data at memory address in most programming languages (for example, via "references" in C++).
myVar="hello"
alterContents(Pointer(globals(),'myVar'))
print(myVar) # would print "foobar"

But then Im really just doing the same thing as in my first example - and static language analysers (like PyLance) would not be able to follow this reference (which means operations like variable renames would not work for the string that I feed into the second parameter of Pointer.__init__).
Any thoughts/ideas/links/information would be greatly appreciated.
Real world usecase/motivation
exhaustive  & potentially irrelevant to the question at hand
I'm writing a webserver/ui framework, which as a part of I've been working to implement a convenient way of exposing server-side variables to the UI, via a method "property" that helps generate a editable text field as HTML with JavaScript that communicates to the backend any changes to the textfield (where the webserver then in its turn modifies the variable that were originally fed to the "property" method that helped create the html).
This is what it looks like:
import fast
myVar="hello"
ui=fast.ui3.Ui()
@ui.page(url='')
def main(request: fast.ui3.Request):
    global myVar
    layout=fast.ui3.HtmlGen() # A class with a series of attributes "box", "text", "property" that are all classes inheriting from `HtmlGen` itself.
    text=layout.box(color='red').text(text="hi!!")
    layout.property(myVar) # property creates a editable text field, that once edited propages the changes to myVar. This is where the issue arrise, as the only way I know of to make this possible, would be to implement it like property(dictionary:dict,key:str) as per the first example in this SO question (which is both verbose & makes variable renames & other operations performed by static language analysers more difficult).
    layout.box(color='red').property(request.client.data.myVar2) # data is a data store that behaves much like a class with attributes on it, implemented using functions like __getattr__ (I control the implementation of this data store, so its implementation might be able to change to accomodate any solutions to this SO question that would be otherwise incompatible with this class), secondary goal is to also make this compatible with whatever syntax I end up with (using a syntax like property(dictionary:dict,key:str) would work fine, but for reasons mentioned above (and in other places of this post) I would like to avoid this if possible)
    
    return layout.render() # Returns html as a string, that gets sent to the client. The html contains JavaScript that communicates
                           # with the webserver whenever the user interacts with the UI generated by HtmlGen()(...).property, so that
                           # the value which "property" represents is always synced to the variable that was originally fed to the `property` function
ui.run() # Blocking function that starts the webserver


Can you please provide an actual example where the solution you are looking for would work, and where you currently don't have something that works like that? Your second example suggests you only need a solution that does something (unclear) to your own classes, but for the first example you claimed to be "looking for a way of creating a pointer to any abstract variable (where I do not control how/where that variable is created & stored)" - this seems contradictory, and it's entirely unclear in what example use case any of this would be useful.

Python doesn't have pointers, there's no way to get a reference to a variable like in C or C++.

@Grismar I suppose my question could be simplified to, "can I get a reference to a variable in a syntactically pleasant manner, where static language extensions such as PyLance can follow the refence". Where "reference", means, some form of object that lets me modify the contents of the original "variable" somehow passed to the function (which in all my examples is called "myVar").

@Grismar So from a practical point of view, the first example in my question really achieves everything I need, but I do not like that I have to pass my "reference" in 2 arguments, where one of them is a string that PyLance would not understand (I hope that makes sense!)

There's no generic way to do this, and this makes sense. There's no way for Python to guarantee to your function that the variable you intend to assign to will still be around once you decide to assign something. If what you pass in is an object with a method you can call later, you can keep that object in your class, which more or less does what you want - but won't work for just any existing type. Barmar already closed your question to another one that's essentially asking the same, although I suspect you won't find the answer you want there. Ask a more targeted question if you need more.

@Grismar I see, thank you. I added my real-world example to the question, but I believe it has been answered already. As such I will just settle for the syntax in my first example (passing a dictionary & a key to effectively substitute a pointer/reference)
